# Does Apache's ContextMap Need To Be Explicitly Cleaned Up?

Tags: java, memory, log4j2

As I was poking around in the ThreadContext documentation I noticed this gem:

[removeStack()](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html#removeStack())

> Each thread that created a diagnostic context by calling push(java.lang.String) should call this method before exiting. Otherwise, the memory used by the thread cannot be reclaimed by the VM.
>
> If you never call it, then your application is sure to run out of memory.

What terrifies me is that even if I read the class description entirely, the entire `Method Summary` section, [ThreadContext.clearStack() Method Details](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html#clearStack()) and [ThreadContext.push(java.lang.String) Method Details](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html#push(java.lang.String)); I never would have seen a reference to this (apparently extremely necessary) method.

I don't happen to be using [ThreadContext.push(java.lang.String)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html#push(java.lang.String)), only [ThreadContext.put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), so I *think* that means I'm in the clear with regards to memory issues, but I'd like to be sure.

Is there anything I have to do with the ThreadContextMap to make sure the thread's memory is able to be reclaimed, e.g. clearMap(), clearAll(), or some other form of deletion?

Empirical testing might tell me whether there's a memory leak in my test case, on my System's environment, or not, but I'm interested in guarantees that hold across applicable Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

The ThreadContextMap and Stack are maintained in a ThreadLocal variable. In a servlet environment (such as Tomcat) if you don't clear up the items in the Map then the next request will still have those values even if they don't apply to that request. So in an environment like that you definitely want to clear the Map at the end of every request.

The stack problem is a bit different. If you push items on the stack at the beginning of the request and then don't pop them off they will still be there when the next request comes in, which presumably will push new values on the stack that also will not be popped off.

Whether you have a problem or not simply depends on what kind of application you are creating. If you have thread pools like Tomcat does then you have to understand how ThreadLocals will behave in that environment.

Comment: Lets say our app validates XML files, and its command line interface has 2 commands:
The `validate <xmlfile>` command which prints detailed validation errors out to console immediately.
The `watch <input_dir> <output_dir>` command however spawns a background process that watches the dir, and for each `<xmlfile>` it detects in `<input_dir>`, creates a `<xmlfile>.isvalid` or `<xmlfile>.notvalid` in `<output_dir>`. Obviously, both re-use common code but one should print errors to console, other to logfile, so we store `isInteractive` in the Map which is used in a log4j2.xml ThreadContextFilter.

Comment: If I understand you properly, you're saying the Map and Stack can both be re-used over and over if e.g. you're reusing threads over and over from a ThreadPool, but the Map usually will just be overwriting the same key-value pairs over and over (which might be a logical issue but shouldn't be a memory issue), while the Stack getting pushed onto would be a huge memory issue. What about non-thread pooled situations? The documentation for removeStack() made me worried that not calling it could prevent cleanup of memory for threads that are never re-used. Was I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: If you never push things onto the stack, there's no need to worry. If you do, then you need to clean up after yourself like you do when opening a file or a database connection.